# OpenGL Bind same program again

Tags: opengl

Does OpenGL check whether the program I want to bind is already bound? Or do I have to do this myself?
I want to switch shaders depending on whether the object has a normal map.

Comment: Are you asking if it causes any issues to bind the same program twice in a row?

Comment: I think it's implementation dependant, better just to bind rather than do the check yourself. Branching is probably a lot slower than binding a shader program!

Comment: What about using a "flat" or "blank" normal map for those objects that don't have normal maps.  This normal map wouldn't perturb any normals but would save you the program switch as well as the branch.

Comment: @zero298 Thats how I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Binding a different GLSL program every time you draw an object would definitely be inefficient. FBOs and GLSL programs have some of the highest validation cost of all object types. Any smart implementation is going to know when you bind the same program and avoid any of that extra work, but state caching to avoid redundant binds is still useful.

However, real performance gains are possible if you sort all draws in such a way that *opaque* objects without normal maps are all drawn together and then *opaque* objects with them are drawn together. Opaque geometry does not have a strict order dependence, so you can minimize shader changes doing something like that. That is what you should be aiming at, rather than trying to minimize redundant binds (which the driver probably already does).